# Resetting a Stack Panel height to dynamic

Tags: c#, wpf, stackpanel

If no height is set, a Stack Panel's height is dynamic based on its contents. My question is: if the c# code sets the height, is there a way (in c#) to wipe those values out and return the Stack Panel to sizing dynamically? Something like this...

```
spnTest.Height = 100; //expands height to 100, even if contents don't fill it
spnTest.HeightIsDynamic = true; //allows the height of spnTest to go back to being dynamic and expand/contract based on its contents
```

For some reason, setting the height to double.NaN has no effect...

```
stkTest.Height = 117;
Console.WriteLine($"Height = {stkTest.Height}"); //writes "Height = 117"
stkTest.Height = double.NaN;
Console.WriteLine($"Height = {stkTest.Height}"); //writes "Height = 117"
```

.ClearValue(HeightProperty) also does not work

Comment: Set it to Double.NaN

Comment: setting to double.NaN isn't working. I'll post more code

Comment: Is there a MinHeight, or style that might be overriding it?

Comment: Have you tried invalidating the control?

Answer (score 1):

A StackPanel initially measures the needed size of the element by using the sizes of the child elements contained within.  This initial measurement should be stored in DesiredSize.  I would try using the height that is stored there to get the original measurement for the Element.  Check out MSDN entry.

[MSDN StackPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.stackpanel?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: I am in a situation where some of the contents in the stack panel are collapsed or visible based on the situation, and I am animating the expansion and collapsing of the entire stack panel. Once I animate it once, the height is set, and it no longer resizes based on its contents. DesiredSize is staying at the first height the stack panel was, as you explained.